# Static library portability

Tags: c++, linux, linker, static-libraries

Short question. If I have written C++ static library and compiled it using G++ on Ubuntu, can I assume safely that it will be possible to link it using G++ on other distributions of Linux?

Comment: No you can't. You probably need to cross compile it for the specific target system and CPU.

Comment: Cross compile it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's too broad to elaborate here. Try to google ABIs and cross compiling please.

Comment: You can only assume that it will be possible to link it safely using the same exact version of `gcc`, and with the same exact versions of C++ shared libraries your static library was linked to, and on the same CPU family. Although `gcc` and `libstdc++` do have some backwards-compatible ABI guarantees, I wouldn't rely on it, and would only assume that it will be compatible with the same exact version of gcc.

Comment: Short answer:  no.    It depends on what your library does, what other libraries it relies on and whether they're installed on other systems, whether it depends on a particular hardware (32-bit, 64-bit, ...), etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binaries aren't arbitrarily interchangeable amongst linux systems, no matter if executables, static libraries or shared libraries.

That's why almost all software packages are distributed as source, and your package manager system takes care of how to configure and compile these.

That said, commercial software, which should be distributed without disclosing the actual source code, is usually (cross-)compiled by the vendor for various linux distributions.

Comment: So proper approach should look like that: 

I want to create open source library - I am providing the source,
I want to create commercial library - I am compiling amongst various targets

Is that right?

Comment: @AkasataAkasata For open source you might consider to provide an _automake package_, for commercial you have to compile it for the various distributions you consider to support, and deliver the binaries.